# cytoscape neural handwriting recognition

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cordova-chrome-app

am new to neural nets and algorithm as a whole but i have a project to build a handwriting recognition app. i currently am using HTML canvas and am get the x,y coords of each point into a list, but i need to build the ML part so my question are: can i use cytoscape.js for handwriting recognition app, if yes, will the input data be x,y coords or pixel(i have been reading on neural networks they seem to favor pixels) and lastly are their any tutorials show samples of something similar with cytoscape.js?

Answer (score 0):

(1) (x, y) coords are pixel/rendered coords at the origin (0, 0) with zoom 1.

(2) You can use Cytoscape.js for any graph theory related subject area.

Comment: I beg you not to be offended but how/what does x,y work as pixels any formula?

Comment: The (x,y) positions of nodes indicate their position in pixels so long as the viewport is at the origin. If you're running headlessly, you can assume that model positions are in pixels.  See http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/position